# Transition from Lucene to Solr (with SolrJ as client) - Querying?

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj

It was very unfortunate, when I made the transition from Lucene to Solr, to see how SolrJ had such basic implementation. Lucene's Querying API is much much more complete, giving me total power.

I come here to ask if anyone has had any trouble using a Lucene's BooleanQuery.toString() into SolrQuery(String query)?

Example:

```
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery(...stuff...);
SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery(booleanQuery.toString());
```

What are the side effects of using the strategy above? Any pros, any cons?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

That should work as long as you keep your queries very simple, but fall apart if you go much beyond that.  Lucene query syntax is not capable of representing all possible queries produced by the lucene query API.  The output of `Query.toString()` may not accurately represent everything about the query object, and often is not valid query syntax at all.

Comment: The answer is actually to use the q.alt parameter when issuing the query using dismax. I made hard research on this.

Comment: Neither dismax nor edismax will support anything that `Query.toString()` outputs, either.

Comment: Hmm I will have to find this out then.